# EmbeddedRecordsMixin not working as expected, what am I missing?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm trying to use embedded records in ember data and I think I'm missing something fundamental.

I have two models

app/models/video.js:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  transcriptions: DS.hasMany('transcription', { embedded: 'always' })
});
```

app/models/transcription.js:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  video: DS.belongsTo('video')
});
```

I also have a custom serializer app/serializers/video.js:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs:{
    transcriptions: { embedded: 'always' }
  },  
  extractSingle: function (store, type, payload, id) {
    var data = payload.data;
    return {
      id: data._id,
      title: data.Title,
      transcriptions: [{ id: "1" }] 
    }
  }
});
```

I would expect that this would result in my video model being populated with transcriptions being an array of transcription object but instead I get the following error:

> "Error while processing route: videos.show" "Assertion Failed: Ember
>   Data expected a number or string to represent the record(s) in the
>   `transcriptions` relationship instead it found an object. If this is a
>   polymorphic relationship please specify a `type` key. If this is an
>   embedded relationship please include the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` and
>   specify the `transcriptions` property in your serializer's attrs
>   object."

Any suggestions of what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: The solution was to modify my custom serializer to the following:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs:{
    transcriptions: { embedded: 'always' }
  },  
  extractSingle: function (store, type, payload, id) {
    var data = payload.data;

    var videoPayload = {
      id: data._id,
      title: data.Title,
      transcriptions: [{ id: "1" }] 
    };

    return this._super(store, type, videoPayload, id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Right - completely missed that - sorry I read the question too fast and focused on purely the error.. EmbeddedRecordsMixin - of course it's a complete record..

Comment: Yes, I've stripped out a bunch of stuff to try and focus on the cause. The transcription model will have other attributes etc. once I work out what's causing the error here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the fact you're reimplementing `extractSingle` yourself.

You should call `this.super` if you're doing this..

In `extractSingle` on the REST Serializer it calls the `normalize` function - this `normalise` function is where the EmbeddedRecordsMixin does all it's work.

Because you're not calling either `this.super` or manually calling `this.normalize` you miss out on what the mixin is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion transcriptions needs to be an array of models though

Comment: I've completely rewritten my answer and undeleted it - I believe I've got it right this time (:

Comment: `this._super(...arguments);`

Comment: OK that answer makes complete sense. I have implemented extractSingle manually because the data coming back from our API is in a horrible shape.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit about how and where I should call super? Simply populating a video object and then doing

Comment: return this._super(store, type, video, id);

Comment: throws an "Assertion Failed: Expected an object as `data` in a call to `push`" error

Comment: The 'video' object should look more like this: { video: { id: data._id, title: data.Title, transcriptions: [{ id: "1" }] } }

Comment: Rather than this: { id: data._id, title: data.Title, transcriptions: [{ id: "1" }] }

Comment: If you take a look at the example in the doc - http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractSingle - the payload being used in this._super() looks like this: payload = { comments: comments, post: payload };